# More GPU Ram or faster speed?

Tags: graphics-cards

What is better for blender rendering (Cycles X)

More GPU RAM (8GB, 128-bit), or faster speeds (6gb, 192-bit)

AKA

Radeon RX 5500 XT or Radeon RX 5600 XT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enourmous things to load in, more ram is probably better, but if you do pretty small things, faster ram is better

Also the difference between a 5500xt and 5600xt is bigger than only the ram. The 5600XT has much more compute units than the 5500xt, and therefore, its way more powerful (according to amd.com, 14.38 TFLOPS for the 5600xt vs 5.6 TFLOPS for the 5500xt). I think for most applications you are better off with the 5600XT.